# Efficent painting of sprites in cairo

Tags: haskell, paint, cairo

I'm using cairo (specifically, the haskell bindings for it) to render a game world every tick. As it is now, I'm generating my entities by creating rotating and translating,creating a path, and filling it. I'm looking for a much more efficient way to handle doing this. What I'd ideally like to do would be to create some sort of sprite and just copy it onto the surface at the correct coordinates.

How would I go about doing this? Or, if I'm thinking of this the wrong way, how should I do it otherwise? I don't really have experience with game making or cairo and I'm just doing this for fun. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The [clock demo](http://code.haskell.org/gtk2hs/cairo/demo/Clock.hs) includes a complete example of how to cache a cairo render. See especially the `redrawStaticLayers` action:

```
let redrawStaticLayers = do
      (width, height) <- widgetGetSize window
      drawWin <- widgetGetDrawWindow window
      background <- createImageSurface FormatARGB32 width height
      foreground <- createImageSurface FormatARGB32 width height
      let clear = do
            save
            setOperator OperatorClear
            paint
            restore
      renderWith background $ do
        clear
        drawClockBackground True width height
      renderWith foreground $ do
        clear
        drawClockForeground True width height
      writeIORef backgroundRef (Just background)
      writeIORef foregroundRef (Just foreground)
```